# Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers for ubuntu 15.04

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I just followed the instructions to install Broadcom Drivers,every thing is working but at last instruction `sudo apt-get install <bcmwl-kernel-source>`,it just say:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package bcmwl-kernel-source
```

And no thing happened after I rebooted my system. 
I use Ibuntu 15.04 and pci id is [14e4:4365] (rev 01)

Comment: why those < and > symbols?

Answer (score 5):

1. Add `restricted` component repository

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository restricted
   ```
2. Update packages list

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Confirm that you have kernel headers installed and updated

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-generic
   ```
4. Then install it again

   ```
   sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
   ```

Comment: also the same problem

Comment: Which of the four steps above failed? All, some or just the last one?

Comment: from second step

Comment: W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
wissem@wissem-Inspiron-3543:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-generic is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
wissem@wissem-Inspiron-3543:~$ sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package bcmwl-kernel-source

Comment: Are you connected to internet?

Comment: yes im using wi-fi

Comment: @WissemRiahi, do you have restricted network connection? APT was not able to connect Ubuntu repository server