# Cant find wifi and wifi drivers

Tags: wireless, wifi-hardware-switch

Hi i am installed the ubuntu 16.04 as dual boot with windows 10. I can't connect to wifi in ubuntu. And additional drivers also dosent shows the drivers. If i running the command.
    lspci

the terminal shows list in the image.

[image]

It doesn't shows any drivers.
I tried to install driver using following command.

```
sudo get-apt install bcmwl-kernal-resource
```

But it shows as

```
E : Unable to locate package bcmwl-kernal-resource
```

Please any one help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn on your computer with windows and you should turn on your wifi. After that, restart your computer with ubuntu. Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I also recently have the similar type of issues with ubuntu 16.04. For development its better to use standard version like ubuntu 14.04 LTS if you recently installed. Anyway you need to be fight to get rid of it try to run this once ::

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

It will restart the network service and if its already drivers installed it may work.

Hope this link gives you a better idea on how to install broadcom wireless drivers 
[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers for ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671251/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers-for-ubuntu-15-04)

Comment: Not working. I checked my network device in windows.  The network device was RTL8723B

Comment: Which laptop you 're working on?
CONFIG!

Comment: Micromax ignite. Pentium quad and4 gb ram.