# Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade does not find internal wifi card

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04

I just upgraded from 17.10 to 18.04. Once the installation was complete, follow with resetting the computer, I could not log to the wifi anymore, "No Wifi Adapter found".

Here is a wireless and network diagnose report of my computer [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/72wZv2Jb8G/)

miker:~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you are referring to his post, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2392454, well I tried Jermy31on page one, but did not solve my problem. Furthermore, multiple requests on that post asked people to start a new post of their problem instead of posting new commets.

Comment: In your paste, it shows that you have a Broadcom device: "Broadcom Limited BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0]" Please refer to the answer in the duplicate for instructions to install the correct driver.

Comment: Hey chili555, thank you for your help and your effort across the duplicate link you referred me to. 

So I did follow the instructions but ended at a dead end. 

miker:~$ sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package bcmwl-kernel-source is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'bcmwl-kernel-source' has no installation candidate

Thanks

Comment: Solved it with: 
sudo add-apt-repository restricted

https://askubuntu.com/questions/671251/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers-for-ubuntu-15-04