# No Wifi Adapter Found on HP Laptop - 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, kernel, broadcom

My laptop:
HP 15-DA1006NT 5MM06EA i5-8265U 4GB 1TB 128GB SSD 2GB MX110 15.6 FreeDOS

I installed 18.04 Ubuntu both with 3rd party hardware and without them. I have same problem:
"No wifi adapter found"

iwconfig

**

eno1 no wireless extension

lo no wireless extension

**

When I wrote "rfkill", I didn't have any results or error.

I looked the old topics and populer solution is bcmwl-kernel-source. However, when I wrote bcmwl-kernel-source to ınstall to termınal, I took this error:

unable to locate package bcmwl-kernel-source

Then I researced this error's solution.

[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers for ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671251/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers-for-ubuntu-15-04)
This topic doesn't work for me.

and I've tried a few more things like that, but it didn't work. What are your solution suggestions?

Comment: What is the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280`?

Comment: @Graham No, I've checked that topic.

Comment: @Kulfy outout is: 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec: d723] 
Subsystem: Hewlett Packard Company Service [103c:8319]

Comment: You have realtek's wireless device m Installing drivers of broadcom will give no results. Try the answer of pomsky or chili555 on above question.

Comment: At that topic, it is said that I have to have "linux-headers" for the respective kernel(s) and "build-essential" package installed. However, I don't have them. For example I try to install build-essential and I took this error: "Package build-essential is missing, has been obsoleted or is only available from another source. E: Package 'build essential' has no installation candidate. I can't make the first step @Kulfy

Comment: You need to have temporary internet connection.

Comment: @Kulfy now I have a temporary internet connection; however, I couldn't solve this "has no installation candidate" error. I take this error for almost all packages like build-essential.

Comment: Did you run a `sudo apt update` before? If not, do that and then try installing the packages again.